# How to select element value without attaching state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For some reason, the showNumber variable gets updated upon submit click, but not in

in return statement. Anyhow, is there a better way to write this? Keep in mind the line in

should not simply change with every input onChange but rather, only after a submit button click. I suppose one solution would be to select input via refs, but I'm hoping there's a better way. Please help.

```
function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  let showNumber = 0;
  const rerender = () => {
    showNumber = number;
  }
  const handleChange = (e) => { setNumber(e.target.value) }
  return (
      <header>
        <input type='number' onChange={handleChange}  />
        <button type='submit' onClick={rerender}>submit</button>
        <p>the number is {showNumber}</p>
      </header>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Why you want to do this? You can maintain another state to update number. But i dont think it make sense or another option you can use form.

Comment: Why do you update your showNumber variable this way?

Comment: Not really for any purpose. Just really wanted to figure out the how.

Answer (score 0):

By Wrapping the form tag you can achieve, so when you click on the submit only it will get the form values and you can fetch the values by using name attribute

**Sample Code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);

  const rerender = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(e.target);
    setNumber(data.get("number"));
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <form onSubmit={rerender}>
        <input type="number" name="number" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <p>the number is {number}</p>
    </header>
  );
}
export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59286425-so-4ch40)

Comment: I also learns from stackoverflow :) If it worked for you kindly accept and vote it so it will be helpful for others to find the solution